# Dismiss Login Screen in iOS when using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    parseLoginHelper = ParseLoginHelper {[unowned self] user, error in
        // Initialize the ParseLoginHelper with a callback
        if let error = error {
            // 1
            ErrorHandling.defaultErrorHandler(error)
        } else  if let _ = user {
            // if login was successful, display the TabBarController
            // 2
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController")
            // 3
            self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated:true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

So I understand that the code here should be able to replace my login screen upon hitting login, however, it does not. Instead it loads and stays on the login screen for parse. However, if I exit the app, it loads the proper screen. Does anyone have any ideas how to dismiss login screen more efficiently upon login?

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()

let startViewController: UIViewController;

if (user != nil) {
    // 3
    // if we have a user, set the TabBarController to be the initial view controller
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    startViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
} else {
    // 4
    // Otherwise set the LoginViewController to be the first
    let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
    loginViewController.fields = [.UsernameAndPassword, .LogInButton, .SignUpButton, .PasswordForgotten]
    loginViewController.delegate = parseLoginHelper
    //loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = parseLoginHCelper

    startViewController = loginViewController
}

// 5
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = startViewController;
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return false
}
```

Comment: so you are adding some subview and you are opening that viewcontroller inside? where is this init?

Comment: @Lu_ not sure if I understand you question?

Comment: so i will ask in other way, we have no idea what your code should replace because we don't know where this init is, could you show me something more that that?

Comment: @Lu_ so here is the rest of my AppDelegate. The parse login splash screen should come up first. Upon hitting log in, I should be able to be moved to the TabBarViewController, however, instead, I am kept at the login spalsh screen. Sorry super new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not call

```
 self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

instead if you already in some controller why just go to tabBar like that:

```
presentViewController(tabBarController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: same problem as above.. it says present is a unresolved member

Answer (score 0):

You should not use :

```
 self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(tabBarController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Try to change that line by :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! tabBarController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and in your storyboard, set the storyboard id of tabBarController under identity inspector to : tabBarController

Comment: tried that.. gives me presentViewController has no member present